# Is substitution linking possible in the vi editor?

Tags: vim, vi

I am trying to edit with two conditions in the vi.

example text)

```
hello world!
-apple watermelon
test text
```

two condition must be met.

1. start with -
2. I want to replace only the first letter of a word with a html tag (The first letter may not be the alphabet)

I tried substitution via pipe in vi, but i cant

**Expected**

```
hello world!
-<b>a</b>pple <b>w<b>atermelon
test text
```

Comment: What did  you try?

Comment: i tried to use pipeline to meet two condition. but i cant find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
:g/^-/s#\<\(.\)#<b>\1</b>#g
```

Meaning:

- for every line that starts with `-` (`:g/^-/`)
- substitute

  - the first character after a break (`\<\(.\)`) (while capturing it)
  - replace it with `<b>\1</b>` (`\1` referencing the captured value)
  - multiple times per line (the `g` flag, remove this unless `:set gdefault?` returns `nogdefault`)